# Is it OK to use 2 foreign keys in a table, one of which must be null?

Tags: mysql, sql, null, foreign-keys

If I have a table where each row is a customer booking, is it OK to have 2 foreign keys in this table: one which will be null and the other referencing the primary key approriate. The reason I have two tables with the foreign key constraint applied to this table is that a booking can either be a reservation of a package of services (service_package) or a single service (service).

My guess is that this is bad design because it becomes possible to register two kinds of bookings in the same booking row, unless enforcing restrictions by using functions or stored procedures.

Is this solution OK or are there better ways to do this, like creating a more general table for the services provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a reasonable approach.  The joins will fail when the the values are `NULL` for a particular column.

In MySQL, you have to enforce this with a trigger.  Other databases have the concept of a "check constraint" where you can enforce that exactly one of the two value is populated.

If you have more columns, you might be tempted to switch to a "type" column along with an "id".  This requires that all the ids have the same type.  It also requires a trigger to ensure that the columns are populated correctly.  And, it can lead to errors when doing joins.

Of the two alternatives, I prefer your method for just two ids.

Comment: Thank you! The "1 null FK + 1 not null FK" enforced by a trigger for respective FK inserted, seems appropriate for this case. It is however tempting to try to create a model that does not rely on triggers for proper normalization, but I guess this falls into the impedance mismatch category. 

It would have been nice if there was some kind of either/or notation that could be applied to these FKs, simliar to what we have in OO modelling. Maybe I can just add an {OR} or {EXCLUSIVE} or similar to the relationship lines to respective table that the FKs reference.

Comment: MySQL has `CHECK` constraints too now, but they can't be used in conjunction with `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Although having nullable FKs is not wrong, from a performance point of view is not always advisable. As correctly mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999454/foreign-key-null-performance-degradation):

B-tree indexes are most effective for high-cardinality data (i.e. columns with many possible values, where the data in the column is unique or almost unique). If you will be having many NULL values (or any other repeated value), the query optimizer might choose not to use the index to filter the records for your result set, since it would be faster to do a table scan.

I would opt for having type/id columns with a compound index (id,type).

Comment: Thanks! Interesting performance points. These will probably come in handy once I've read up on the more technical aspects of relational DB's. At present, I am mainly concerned with making the the database structure as coherent, safe and easy to maintain as possible.